# What Does Rated Load of a Tactile Switch Mean?

Tags: voltage, current, basic

I want to connect a tactile switch to an GPIO pin of MSP430 (which runs on 3.3 volts). The datasheet of the micro-controller says that IO pins can withstand max current of 6mA.

The tactile switch I am interested in has rated load of 12V and 50mA.

What does it mean? Does the switch draws power when it is closed?! Can I use the switch with that micro-controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, yes you can use the switch with that microcontroller. Its 50mA rating means you can't use it for higher currents, say to drive a motor directly.

Second, if an IO pin on a micro can withstand 6 mA, that means it can supply 6mA when it is an output, for example to drive a LED, or to drive a transistor to control a motor.

If you're connecting a switch to it, you'll also set the pin (in your program) to be an input, and the current it will take is tiny (microamps).

Normally you would either:

connect the switch from the pin to 0V, and a resistor from the same pin to +v, or
connect the switch from the pin to +V, and a resistor from the same pin to 0v.

The resistor will have a fairly high value, maybe 5k or 10k (or up to 47k). It pulls the pin to the supply rail it is connected to : if +v it pulls the pin high, and you will read '1' in the micro. Press the switch and it will pull the pin to 0V, conducting the current through that resistor (a milliamp or less) to ground. And as the pin is now 0V, you will read '0' from that pin in the micro.

Answer (score 3):

Rated power means that the switch can withstand 12V when opened and when closed a maximum current of 50mA.

The maximum current of the IO pins of the uC refers to the case that they are used as outputs. When connecting a switch you configure them as inputs and activate an internal pullup. Then you connect the switch to GND and an IO pin. Usually the internal pullups are in the range of 10k so the switch is going to see 3.3V when opened and 3.3V/10k=0.33mA when closed.